# Supabase storage file upload from React Native times out, video file gets corrupted

Tags: react-native, supabase

I use the following code for uploading videos from my React Native app to Supabase storage:

```
const fileExt: string = videoUri.split('.').pop() ?? 'mov'
const filePath = `users/${session?.user?.id ?? 'unknown'}/${formatFileDateTime()}.${fileExt}`
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('files', {
  uri: videoUri,
  name: filePath,
  type: `video/${fileExt}`
})
console.log('updatePostWithVideo 1', { postId, videoUri, filePath })
const { error: uploadError } = await supabase.storage.from(STORAGE_BUCKET_VIDEOS).upload(filePath, formData, { cacheControl: '3600' })
if (uploadError != null) throw uploadError
console.log('updatePostWithVideo 2')
const { publicURL, error: urlError } = supabase.storage.from(STORAGE_BUCKET_VIDEOS).getPublicUrl(filePath)
if (urlError != null) throw urlError
console.log('updatePostWithVideo 3', { publicURL, filePath })
```

I never reach 'updatePostWithVideo 2', instead I get an error (timeout?) before that.

On https://app.supabase.com/ in the Storage file browser, after a while it says “File is corrupted, please delete and reupload this file again”

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I’m on the Pro plan so the 50 MB limit does not apply.

Comment: How large is your video file? There is 50MB upload size limit on free account as per https://supabase.com/pricing.

Comment: @BoLu Thanks, made an update: I’m on the Pro plan so the 50 MB limit does not apply.

Comment: Can you try upload a small file first? If it is working, then iterate again with gradually increased file size. I suspect it might be caused by network interruption.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, that even though you are on Pro plan, you will need to update your max storage size size setting here:

https://app.supabase.com/project/_/storage/settings